# ReactHooks: Invoke callback when store value changes

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I'm learning how to use ReactHooks correctly. I encountered an issue as described below:

I'm using [Nav component](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/nav) from for a third party library. My component using hooks looks like this:

```
  //using redux selector to get value from state 
  const { screenType } = useSelector((state: IStateStore) => ({
    screenType: state.screenType
  }));

  // dummy use effect to see when store's screentype is being updated
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("screentype in effect", screenType); //prints updated when store changes
  }, [screenType]);

  //onRender callback I pass to my third party component
  const onRenderLink = (link: INavLink) => {
    console.log("Screen Type inside :", screenType);//never gets executed after screentype updates
    return (<>Hello</>);
  };

  return (
      <Navigation
        groups={[]}
        onRenderLink={onRenderLink}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

My problem is:

- When my component renders, the onRenderLink is invoked which calls my function onRenderLink with default screenType value from store. \
- When store's screenType value changes, my useEffect hook prints the updated value but at this time I have no way to reinvoke my onRenderLink because it was already invoked earlier.

How can I cause the screenType value change to invoke onRenderLink again? I tried doing.

```
  <Navigation
        className="sectionTabs"
        groups={[]}
        onRenderLink={React.useCallback(onRenderLink, [screenType])}
  />
```

I thought when screenType changes, this will retrigger my callback method but that's not what is happening. 
Thanks for your help

Comment: how is screentype relevant to your Navigation and onRenderLink func?

Comment: It is relevant because the nav component renders differently based on the screentype. For simplicity I have removed the logic of onRenderLink function but there is some work going on there that needs to be redone based on screentype value.

Answer (score 0):

Try providing `screenType` as a `key` of Navigation

```
<Navigation
        key={screenType}
        groups={[]}
        onRenderLink={onRenderLink}
      />
```

Comment: mmm ok, now this is weird. When a component key changes react destroys it an re-render the component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook as you are expecting `onRenderLink()` to get invoked and return a value every time `screenType` changes.

It should be implemented this way:

```
  //using redux selector to get value from state 
  const { screenType } = useSelector((state: IStateStore) => state);

  // dummy useEffect to see when store's screenType is being updated
  useEffect(() => {
    //prints updated screenType when store changes
    console.log("screenType in useEffect", screenType);
  }, [screenType]);

  //onRenderLink gets invoked every time screenType updates and returns <>Hello</>
  const onRenderLink = useMemo((link: INavLink) => {
    //prints updated screenType when store changes
    console.log("screenType in onRenderLink", screenType);

    return (<>Hello</>);
  },[screenType]) // need to pass screenType to dependency list

  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation
        groups={[]}
        onRenderLink={onRenderLink}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Let me know if you need any further explanation with this :)